# Cant get filemask to work properly in multi-line WinSCP command-line in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to use WinSCP to create a PowerShell script to automate an SFTP transfer. I am able to connect and do simple transfers, but I want to transfer yesterdays files only. For that I need a filemask which I can't get to work.

Below is my code. I am taking this script, putting it in Notepad++, saving it as a PowerShell script and running it. The SFTP connection part works as I have used this to grab all files on the SFTP. So I am sure its the file mask part.

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" `
  /log="\\blah\blah\users\vmedhe\thing.log" /ini=nul `
  /command `
    "open sftp://username:password@sftpsite -hostkey=`"`"not real host key=`"`"" `
    "cd /" `
    "lcd C:\Test_case" ` 
    "get -filemask=`"`">yesterday`"`" shares" `
    "get -filemask=`"`">yesterday`"`" *.*" `
    "exit"

$winscpResult = $LastExitCode
if ($winscpResult -eq 0)
{
  Write-Host "Success"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Error"
}

exit $winscpResult
```

Unfortunately I keep getting errors:

```
At C:\Powershell_Scripts\mXpress_main.PS1:9 char:2
+     "get -filemask=`"`">yesterday`"`" *.*" `
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Unexpected token '"get -filemask=`"`">yesterday`"`" *.*"' in expression or statement. At C:\Powershell_Scripts\mXpress_main.PS1:10 char:5
+     "exit"
+     ~~~~~~ Unexpected token '"exit"' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Something is wrong with my filemask but I am not sure what it is. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the file mask. – You have a space after the backtick at the (seemingly) end of the `lcd` line.

So the backtick escapes the space, and not the newline. Consequently, the `get` line is interpreted as a new PowerShell code line.

It's basically a PowerShell equivalent of this common WinSCP problem with batch-file:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file#newline_escaping

---

*Though in general, [in PowerShell, you should use WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks that was indeed the issue. Below is the final code for all future google's.

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" `
  /log="\\blah\blah\users\fake\thing.log" /ini=nul `
  /command `
    "open sftp://username:password@sftpname/ -hostkey=`"`"junk host key=`"`"" `
    "cd /" `
    "lcd C:\test_area" `
    "get -filemask=`"`">yesterday`"`" shares" `
    "get -filemask=`"`">yesterday`"`" *.*" `
    "exit"

$winscpResult = $LastExitCode
if ($winscpResult -eq 0)
{
  Write-Host "Success"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Error"
}

exit $winscpResult
```